# TypeScript - Can't set type of function to overload

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am trying to set the type of a function to be an overload type that is defined as the property of an interface, but am getting `Binding element 'text' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)` for the function arguments. The overloads all have the same typing for the args so I'm not sure why it's erroring.

[image]

```js
interface Args {
  text: string
}

interface Utils {
  toUpperCase?(args: Args): string
  toUpperCase?(args: Args): any
}

export const toUpperCase: Utils['toUpperCase'] = ({ text }) => text.toUpperCase()
```

It works fine with either overload individually, so if I remove one of them (doesn't matter which), then the error is gone, e.g.

```js
interface Utils {
  toUpperCase?(args: Args): string
  // toUpperCase?(args: Args): any
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `:Args` explicit typing to the function parameter seems to eliminate the compiler error.

```
interface Args {
  text: string
}

interface Utils {
  toUpperCase?(args: Args): string
  toUpperCase?(args: Args): any
}

export const toUpperCase: Utils['toUpperCase'] = ({ text }: Args) => text.toUpperCase()
```

Looks like the inference isn't or maybe can't be made that the function on the right fulfils the signature of `Utils['toUpperCase']` without it.